# Call Ajax inside for Loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, for-loop, call

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    with (x = new XMLHttpRequest()) open("GET","d.php?id=" + i), send(null), onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) alert(i);
    }
}
```

Now I want each time when `readyState = 4`, it should alert correct value of `i` for which URL was called. Currently, it alert only for once and output alert is `5`

Comment: Interesting syntax. Never seen `with` used this way in real life before.

Comment: You should avoid using `with` for various reasons. It will throw an error in strict mode.

Comment: thanks for the comments guys, but my real problem is some thing else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @Wasim: That's why it's a comment and not an answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `with` to retain `i`, you'd either need to add it to an object that also references the `xhr` object:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    with({i:i, xhr:new XMLHttpRequest()}) {
        xhr.open("GET","d.php?id=" + i);
        xhr.send(null);
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
                alert(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Or you'd need to create the xhr outside the `with` and add `i` to it.

```
var xhr;
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){ 
    (xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()).i = i;
    with(xhr) {
        open("GET","d.php?id=" + i);
        send(null);
        onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (readyState == 4 && status == 200)
                alert(i);
        }
    }
}
```

---

But if you want a proper, future-proof solution, make the handler in a variable scope that provides the variables needed for the handler.

```
function doRequest(i, xhr) {
    xhr.open("GET","d.php?id=" + i);
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            alert(i);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    doRequest(i, new XMLHttpRequest());
}
```

---

Or if you insist upon inlining the function as some do, you could do it like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    (function (i, xhr) {
        xhr.open("GET","d.php?id=" + i);
        xhr.send(null);
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
                alert(i);
        }
    }(i, new XMLHttpRequest());
}
```

Comment: Hi, your answer helped solve an issue I was having, but I'm not sure why - was hoping you could explain --
I was initially had all my code for `doRequest` in my for loop, but only the last request would go through. I was creating a new request inside the loop like this `var request = new XMLHttpRequest()` . Once I separated this out into another function and passed the required variables, it all worked. Why is this? Haven't encountered a situation like this before.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the closure captures the `i` variable itself, not just the current value.  I'd personally do something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i ++) (function(i) {
        [..] alert(i) [..]
})(i);
```

Comment: this one is not working, can you please paste the exact code,

Answer (score 1):

Just updating James code to suit your needs

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    with (x = new XMLHttpRequest()) open("GET","d.php?id=" + i), send(null), onreadystatechange = (function(i, x) {
        return function () {
        if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) alert(i);
       }
    })(i, x)
}
```

Hope this helps

Updated it for **x**, this should work

Comment: You're still overwriting `x` in the loop.

Comment: `with` is deprecated in `strict mode`

Answer (score 0):

This is how i sloved it

```
var x = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    with (x[i] = new XMLHttpRequest()) open("GET","d.php?id=" + i), send(null), onreadystatechange = (function(i) {
        return function () {
        if (x[i].readyState == 4 && x[i].status == 404) alert(i);
       }
    })(i)
}
```

but i am interested more in using closure to solve my problem, how can i use closure to solve my issue.

Comment: If you're going to use a closure, you might as well take advantage of the variable scope, and get rid of `with`. I updated my answer with a proper closure example.